# How to prevent CSS inline style when Browser Zoom in?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, zooming, inline

When using Safari or Chrome, I have a problem when using the Zoom-in view tool. On an image slider it forces to add inline style of a DIV element and specifically its height (which obviously overrides any other styles).

The div should be set at 340px, but automatically changes the value to 387px, then 459px etc... incrementally based on zoom level. Also note that the images within the image slider don't change size, and other elements don't change either.

The issue can be seen here [the troubling re-dimension...](http://www.reolian.com.mo/)
After opening the page zoom in 1 or 2 levels then hit refresh while zooming. When I inspect(with firebug) the element Safari and Chrome adds inline styles:

```
<div id="djslider-loader40" class="djslider-loader" style="background-image: none; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; height: 387px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
```

How do I prevent this behavior from the browser?

Comment: There isn't any real way to prevent browsers from zooming, but I'm not sure I'm seeing the problem you're describing. When I zoom in Chrome, everything on the page resizes correctly and looks as it does with a normal zoom.

Comment: @Ktash, sorry I forgot to mention that when you zoom the page and hit refresh (in zoomed version), the div will increase in height. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this code

```
<div id="djslider-loader40" class="djslider-loader" style="background: none;height: 387px !important;">
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I don't quite understand the mechanics behind it (the background:none part), but Thank you!

Comment: when you set background to none, it set all other parts to initial stage so you don't need to write so much extra css, and making height !important will fix it.
cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar kind of issue. One of my div element had an inline style height based on its contents. Hence, if i expand the content from JScript, the content would get hidden. Thanks to the example. When I apply height:100% !important, it worked like a charm! Thanks again.